# Observe livedata with an initial timeout

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata-transformations

I've a livedata which emits everytime there is a update in the database. When the particular screen opens, this livedata emits immediately with whatever value is there in the database. Then, a network call is made to update the database. After the database is updated, the livedata emits again. This leads to two emissions in very quick succession. Subsequent updates to the database work properly cz there is only one emission whenever the database is updated. Only the first time, there are 2 updates in very quick succession. I want to avoid that.

An idea to avoid that would be something like this. When the livedata emits, wait for Xs. If there is another emission in those Xs, discard the data from old emission and use the new one. Wait for Xs again. If there is no emission in those Xs, use the latest data.

This looks very similiar to throttling but only once. I was wondering if there's a simple way to do something like using LiveData or MediatorLiveData.

Comment: hey, I'm kinda confused, you have a livedata which is observing a data, when data changed you want to call network request and after that our livedata will call again.so we have two emission, one in first time activity start up and one after network request, you want to disable first one observing?

Comment: Yeah. kind of like that. I don't want to disable the first emission though. I want to use it if there's no other emission Xs after first emission. If there is an emission within those Xs, i want to repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can post delayed `Runnable` with timeout you want after first `LiveData` event.
Every `LiveData` update remove posted `Runnable` and post it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MediatorLiveData and a boolean val for achieving this.

1. Create a mDbLiveData, mediator livedata mFinalLiveData and boolean mLoadedFromAPI when data from API is loaded.
2. On API success or failure, set mLoadedFromAPI to true;
3. Observe mFinalLiveData in your Activity/Fragment

```
LiveData<Model> mDbLiveData;
MediatorLiveData<Model> mFinalLiveData = new MediatorLiveData();
private boolean mLoadedFromAPI = false;

// Load db data in mDbLiveData
mDbLiveData = // Data from DB
// Add mDbLiveData as source in mFinaliveData
mFinalLiveData.addSource(mDbLiveData, dbData -> {
    if (mLoadedFromAPI) mFinalLiveData.postValue(dbData);
});
```

Comment: The livedata is being returned by another SDK. I don't have information regarding when is the API called.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped. https://medium.com/@guilherme.devel/throttle-operator-with-livedata-and-kotlin-coroutines-ec42f8cbc0b0

I modified the solution a bit to fit my usecase:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.debounceOnce(duration: Long,
                                 coroutineContextProvider: CoroutineContextProvider): LiveData<T> {
    return MediatorLiveData<T>().also { mediatorLivedata ->
        var shouldDebounce = true
        var job: Job? = null
        val source = this

        mediatorLivedata.addSource(source) {
            if (shouldDebounce) {
                job?.cancel()
                job = CoroutineScope(coroutineContextProvider.IO).launch {
                    delay(duration)
                    withContext(coroutineContextProvider.Main) {
                        mediatorLivedata.value = source.value
                        shouldDebounce = false
                    }
                }
            } else {
                job?.cancel()
                mediatorLivedata.value = source.value
            }
        }
    }
}

open class CoroutineContextProvider @Inject constructor() {
    open val Main: CoroutineContext by lazy { Dispatchers.Main }
    open val IO: CoroutineContext by lazy { Dispatchers.Default }
}
```